# How could i get my SVG to stay at the edge of the screen

Tags: css

Hello I'm a Noob at CSS and I'm trying to do a front end mentor challenge but I'm already stuck at trying to recreate this

Photo of what I'm trying to recreate

[image]

How can i move SVGs to the end of the screen

sorry if my question is unclear :')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the only element on the page and the body is the only container you can do the following.

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50vw;
    top: 50%;
  }
```